# iOS - TableView willDisplayCell animation only happen when user scrolling down not to the top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, tableview

Hi am going to animate the table view cell when the user scrolling down if the user scroll to the top the will normally move with out animation.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cells forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    cells.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        cells.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}
```

i tried like this but the animation happen all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Custom cell with Bool Property "**isAnimated**". By Default "**isAnimated**" value is "**NO**".

and do code changes in `willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell` method.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//Typecast UITableViewCell to CustomCell. ex: CustomCell *objCell = (CustomCell *)cell
// check isAnimated or not 
   if(cell.isAnimated) return;
   cell.alpha = 0.0;
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
      cell.alpha = 1.0;
      cell.isAnimated = YES;
   }];
}
```

Here Cell reference is Custom Cell reference. I hope this code works for you

Answer (score 0):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, and UITableViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate. So the delegate you attach to the table view will get events such as [scrollViewDidScroll](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll):, and you can call methods such as contentOffset on the table view to finding the scroll position.

Visit apple doc for more info on [UIScrollViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)

Use scrollViewDidScroll method and then put a condition there to find the scroll direction. And animate on scroll down.

May use the code as below:

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
    CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
    float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
    float h = size.height;

    // NSLog(@"offset: %f", offset.y);   
    // NSLog(@"content.height: %f", size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"bounds.height: %f", bounds.size.height);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.top: %f", inset.top);   
    // NSLog(@"inset.bottom: %f", inset.bottom);   
    // NSLog(@"pos: %f of %f", y, h);

    float reload_distance = 10;
    if(y > h + reload_distance) {
       //write your code here to animate
           //cells.alpha = 0.0;
           //[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
           //cells.alpha = 1.0;
           //}];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment i will check with this in my code

Comment: i tired your way but its returns me a empty cells